# How to make li to take equal space instead of in same line

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need List like this

I have ul in two columns, i want the same margin between each li, but no need of li in each column start at exact place. How to make it work.

example:
I want like this

```
  . List item1    .list item 2 with
                   2 two line content
  .list Item3 with 
   two line        . listitem4

   .listitem5      .list Item6
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRHg6.png

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/d2j1zyhk/

Comment: No I attached an image

Comment: In what way is @UnknownUser 's suggeston wrong? Have you tried it with items of different length and a margin? What have **you** tried?